# Eclipse History Load When Opening Source File

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to automatically load the History tab to show the change history whenever I open a source file in Eclipse?

Right now, I have to right-click `Team -> Show in History`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth tip from https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-119.htm?cp=0_3_16_2_6

> *Tip:* You can have the History view update automatically to the history of the file in the active editor by enabling the **Link with Editor** item in the view's toolbar.